# Django, form can not be submitted

Tags: django, django-forms

I created the form, but i can not submit it using post method. I worked with generic views

When i try to submit it,this link appeares '?csrfmiddlewaretoken=4u6glHHJVueXItlN...'

here's my code:

form template:

```
   <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-body clearfix">

      {% include 'words/word_form.html' %}

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
        </form>
```

generic view:

```
class Create_Word(generic.CreateView):
   model=Word
   fields=['name','translation']
   template_name = "words/list_all.html"
```

Here's word_form template:

```
{%load extra%}




{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group ">

    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger-small">{{ field.errors }}</span>

    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 m-l-1  ">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class= "col-sm-9 m-b-1">
        {{ field | addcss:"form-control" }}
```

```
    </div>

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It seems to me that it somehow using a get method

Comment: Yes, the `?csrfmiddlewaretoken=4u6glHHJVueXItlN...` looks like the form is submitting with a GET request. However, there is nothing in the code you have shown which explains why that would happen, so we can't help.

Comment: What is in `word_form.html`?

Comment: Show us the contents of `words/word_form.html` and we may be able to help you. Also, I don't know if you missed out the closing `</form>` tag in your code as well or you just missed it out when pasting your question. But you need a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Are there actually whitespaces around `=` in form action attribute? Try to remove them.

Comment: @DwayneCrooks There is a closing tag in my code

Comment: @solarissmoke Okay,I included it in the description

Comment: @GwynBleidD Didn't help:(

Comment: Where is your submit button?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Just included my full code,here it is

Comment: You must have some Javascript or something that is messing with the form...

Comment: @solarissmoke There is no Javascript file in my site at all

Comment: @solarissmoke It's weird though that i can not inspect the "form" element, when I look at the structure of my website using devtools(via Chrome)